# Debugging an OSX program on Snow Leopard, which was build on Lion

Tags: xcode, gdb, osx-lion

I have a program which I build using automatic-ref-counting and the Lion SDK. This program doesn't behave as expected in Snow Leopard, (One view won't be loaded and opening a document hangs the program.) so I want to debug it there. But because I can't compile it under Snow Leopard I have no idea how to do so.

So how do I get the debugging symbols into gdb or can I debug this thing in Xcode - is there probably a remote way or something like that?

Comment: What about using a virtual machine ?

Answer (score 1):

You can either debug remotely via `gdbserver`:

```
snow-leopard$ gdbserver :10000 /path/to/exe
lion$ gdb /path/to/exe
(gdb) target remote snow-leopard:10000
```

A simpler way is to copy your entire source and build directory to snow-leopard and debug with GDB locally. Even though you didn't build there, GDB should still be able to find everything it needs.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say, my research shows that the "g++" compiler on Snow Leopard no longer places symbols in the linked module that have any meaning to "gdb".  The only symbols found are the made-up symbols created to make ALL symbols unique.  Here is a brief sample:

```
`_Z5DoSVCi', function, 0x151dd
`_Z7SEBTrapv', function, 0x1383c
```

Those same symbols in Tiger were like this:

```
`_Z5DoSVCi'  `DoSVC(int)', FUNCTION, 0x1394c
`_Z7SEBTrapv'  `SEBTrap()', FUNCTION, 0xf994
```

The "signature" is what "gdb" needs to resolve things like:  break emsvc.c:DoSVC
Furthermore, you must still have all the "object decks", like emsvc.o, because Snow Leopard's "g++" apparently does not carry the symbols in the linked module anymore.

I brought a "g++" compiled module linked on Tiger (Intel-based) over to Snow Leopard without object decks, and "gdb" was able to handle it perfectly, including setting breakpoints.  Apparently, "g++" or the linker isn't producing proper modules for "gdb" on Snow Leopard.